# kivy No Screen with name "main_screen"

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Well, I was trying out with the ScreenManager,and I got a problem with the name.
My app was supposed to start with a HelloScreen and after 3 seconds it would automatically transit to a MainScreen.

These are in my main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class HelloScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MemoryManagementSystem(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MemoryManagementSystem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.transit_scene, 3)

    def transit_scene(self, *args):
        self.current = "main_screen"


class MemoryManagementSystemApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MemoryManagementSystem()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MemoryManagementSystemApp().run()
```

These are in my kv file:

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

MemoryManagementSystem:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    HelloScreen:
        name: "hello_screen"
    MainScreen:
        name: "main_screen"

<HelloScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Project"
            font_size: 50

<MainScreen>:
```

And if I run these, the screen is totally black, with no label shown, and after 3 seconds the app crashed, and I got this:

```
File "C:\Users\98742\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1037, in on_current
     screen = self.get_screen(value)
   File "C:\Users\98742\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1063, in get_screen
     raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "main_screen".
```

But I've already add a screen named "main_screen" in .kv file... I just don't get it.

I read other questions and found out that I can solve this problem by adding the screen in main.py, like this:

```
class MemoryManagementSystem(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MemoryManagementSystem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(HelloScreen(name='hello_screen'))
        self.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main_screen"))
        Clock.schedule_once(self.transit_scene, 3)

    def transit_scene(self, *args):
        self.current = "main_screen"
```

And it does work. But I just don't know why can't my version work?(it doesn't show the label and it crashed). Does it have anything to do with the init and .kv file?

Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: What is the name of your .kv?

Comment: Put your class definitions in your .kv at the top, the .kv acts just like a .py; if you try to instantiate a class before it is defined, it wont work. Read [this](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#rule-context).

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you are not using the `.kv` root, if you want the .kv to load, it must have the same name as the class that inherits from the App in lowercase as indicated by the docs:

> **How to load KV**
>
> There are two ways to load Kv code into your application:
>
> - **By name convention:**
>
> Kivy looks for a Kv file with the same name as your App class in
>   lowercase, minus “App” if it ends with ‘App’ e.g:
>
> MyApp -> my.kv If this file defines a Root Widget it will be attached
>   to the App’s root attribute and used as the base of the application
>   widget tree.
>
> - **Builder:** You can tell Kivy to directly load a string or a file. If
>     this string or file defines a root widget, it will be returned by the
>     method:
>
> `Builder.load_file('path/to/file.kv')`
>
> or:
>
> `Builder.load_string(kv_string)`

In your case it should be called memorymanagementsystem.kv, plus you should not return to overwrite the build method.

**memorymanagementsystem.kv**

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

MemoryManagementSystem:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    HelloScreen:
        name: "hello_screen"
    MainScreen:
        name: "main_screen"

<HelloScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Project"
            font_size: 50

<MainScreen>:
```

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class HelloScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MemoryManagementSystem(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MemoryManagementSystem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.transit_scene, 3)
    def transit_scene(self, *args):
        self.current = "main_screen"

class MemoryManagementSystemApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MemoryManagementSystemApp().run()
```

Another solution is that if you want to use overwrite the method build returning a new one you have to do that in the .kv there is no root so you must change `MemoryManagementSystem:` to `<MemoryManagementSystem>:` as I show below:

**memorymanagementsystem.kv**

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

<MemoryManagementSystem>:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    HelloScreen:
        name: "hello_screen"
    MainScreen:
        name: "main_screen"

<HelloScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Project"
            font_size: 50

<MainScreen>:
```

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class HelloScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MemoryManagementSystem(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MemoryManagementSystem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.transit_scene, 3)
    def transit_scene(self, *args):
        self.current = "main_screen"

class MemoryManagementSystemApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MemoryManagementSystem()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MemoryManagementSystemApp().run()
```

References:

- https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Actually there's no problem with the name of .kv file, and the real problem is the second one. But I still don't understand why can't I overwrite the build method and return a new object if I make a root widget in .kv file?

Comment: @GaryYuan 
It is that if you do not use the `<>:` you are creating a new object that has particular characteristics, but you are passing another object as root in the build that does not have those characteristics. `<>:` is equivalent to continuing to implement the class, without this you are adding features to an object of the class. 
In conclusion with your initial code you are creating 2 objects, an object in the .kv that has the screens and another in the build that does not have screens

Answer (score 0):

## Black/Blank Screen - Two Root Widgets

You have encountered a black/blank screen because there are two root widgets in your Kivy App. One of the root is from main.py i.e. *return MemoryManagementSystem()*. The second root is from kv file i.e. ***MemoryManagementSystem:*** and this declaration is known as the ***root rule***.

The root widget used by the App is the one from main.py i.e., `return MemoryManagementSystem()` which resulted in a black/blank screen.

[Programming Guide » Kv language » Rule context](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#rule-context)

> The root rule is declared by declaring the class of your root widget,
>   without any indentation, followed by : and will be set as the root
>   attribute of the App instance:
>
> Widget: 
> A class rule, declared by the name of a widget class between <
>   > and followed by :, defines how any instance of that class will be graphically represented:
>
> <MyWidget>:

## Problem

The Kivy App is missing the ***class rule*** declaration in the kv file to hook up to the class defined in main.py

## Solution

### kv file

Replace

```
MemoryManagementSystem:
```

with

```
<MemoryManagementSystem>:
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Main Screen]